# How to install AVD separately and use it in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-virtual-device

I downloaded an AVD out of android studio, now I want to use it in it, how can I do that?
the link I downloaded is:

https://https:/dl.google.com/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/x86-26_r10.zip

Thank you

Comment: Are you saying you want to use the AVD apart from Android Studio or within?

Comment: within it, I downloaded it manually from the link above but then I need to install to use it in android studio.

Comment: Does the answer by @whack-panther not help you? Have you have checked the source for this type of info? https://developer.android.com/studio/run/managing-avds if these have not worked let me know and I'll install the AVD on my system tomorrow and see where the issue is

Comment: No his answer didn't really help, I did what he said but android studio didn't recognize the AVD, if you could do so it'll really help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay the process of installing an externally downloaded system image is not super complex and @whack_panther had the idea right.

To make everything work with an external installation you do need to unzip the x86 folder from the downloaded system image to:

**C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-26\google_apis**

In order to find this folder in Windows ensure that you have your hidden folders visible.

The download you provided is API-26 and the Release name is O, keep this in mind because this is where I ran into confusion at first as I already had many sys-images downloaded on my system for development purposes.

**What I did:**

I removed all of my downloaded system images and then placed only the new system image from link you provided in the directory listed above to ensure we were looking at the same data. When I did this, the only available system image that would not require an additional download when I attempted to create a new AVD from the AVD Manager GUI located under “Tools” in the Android Studio menu was:

**Release Name: O | API Level: 26 | ABI: x86 | Target: Android 8 (Google APIs)**

Which is the system image downloaded from the link you provided.

Then set everything up as usual with your externally downloaded system image using the prompts in the AVD Manager and you should be good to go. **Also note that here I was required to create a New Hardware Profile to enable the option to use the newly downloaded system image, I would bet this is because there are settings in the download that do not apply to the built-in hardware profiles**

**One note:** The folder you provided appears to have variations already available from Android Studio so I would suggest looking through the options in the AVD manager before you stick with the idea of downloading external images for these purposes, doing so is obviously supported but it may not be needed so there is no reason to make things more challenging for yourself unless it is completely necessary.

Answer (score 1):

after extracting your sys-image..go to your sdk folder find system-images, then create a folder of the image and paste it in there i.e mine is

**C:\Users\yourname\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\system-images\android-26**

Comment: Does this automatically load the AVD in Android Studio? For example, after completing your steps above, will the OP be able to simply launch the new AVD from the GUI in Android Studio? Try to be as specific as possible as to how the OP can begin using the new AVD in AS, I think it will make for a better answer with this type of question.

Comment: yes as @ViaTech said, the AVD wasn't automatically loaded.

Answer (score 0):

1. Extract the zip at below location :
   C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\system-images\android-26
2. Go to AVD Manager and refresh the system image page. It will be detected/